# What is the correct content-type and document structure for an email that only contains an text/html part

Tags: email, html-email

First off- I'm fixing up an existing open source library.  While I know that people SHOULD send a plaintext version of a message when they send an html email, this isn't a best-practices question.  If I don't maintain backwards compatibility, they won't accept my patch.

I'm trying to figure out how to best handle situations where ONLY an html email is sent.

The library currently generates this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;

Hello, World
```

But every html-only message I've seen in my inbox shows:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_1935495_1732146301.1367384830372"

----=_Part_1935495_1732146301.1367384830372
Content-Type: text/html;

Hello, World
----=_Part_1935495_1732146301.1367384830372--
```

I can't figure out if this is a best-practice or a requirement

I've been through :

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2854.txt

but couldn't find any information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Content-Type: Multipart/related; type=Text/HTML`:

```
From: user1@example.com
To: user2@example.com
Subject: An example
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Base: http://www.example.com
Content-Type: Multipart/related; boundary="boundary-example-1";type=Text/HTML

--boundary-example-1
Content-Type: Text/HTML; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: QUOTED-PRINTABLE

... text of the HTML document, which might contain a hyperlink
to the other body part, for example through a statement such as:
<IMG SRC="/images/ie5.gif" ALT="Internet Explorer logo">
Example of a copyright sign encoded with Quoted-Printable: =A9
Example of a copyright sign mapped onto HTML markup: &#168;
```

**References**

- [MIME Hierarchies of Body Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563064)
- [MIME Standard Header Fields](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fad30590_.htm)
- [Handling Binary Data in XML Documents](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/07/binary/binary.html)
- [Direct Mailer Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee799817)
- [Multipart Messages](http://oreilly.com/openbook/mh/mulmes.htm)
- [HTML Threading:
  Conventions for use of HTML in email](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/NOTE-HTMLThreading-0105)

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  I don't doubt it works - I've been able to jam a lot of different content-types in there, and it still renders right.  I'm just concerned with the proper standard.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco I've added references